# Best architecture for crawling website in application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture

I am working on a product in which we need a feature to crawl the user given URL and publish his separate mobile site. In the crawling process we want to crawl the site content, CSS, images and scripts. The product used to do more activities like scheduling some marketing activities and all. What I want to ask -

what is the best practice and open source framework to do this task?

Should we do it in the application itself or should there be another server for doing this activity (if this activity takes load)? Keep in mind that we have 1 "lacks" user visiting every month publishing his mobile site from the website, and around 1-2k concurrent users.

The application is built in Java and the Java EE platform using Spring and Hibernate as server side technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used Derkley DB Java edition for managing off-heap queue of links to crawl and distinguish between links pending download and ones downloaded yet.

For parsing HTML TagSoup is the best choise in wild internet.

Batik is the choice for parsing CSS and SVG.

PDFBox is awesome and allows to extract links from PDF

Quartz scheduler is intustry-proven choice for event scheduling.

And yes, you will need one or more servers for crawling, one server for aggregating results and scheduling tasks, and perhaps another server for WEB front and back end.

This worked well for http://linktiger.com and http://pagefreezer.com

Comment: Thanx jdevelop. This is the exact solution that i need. I was thinking not to process the html in application itself. One more thing, in which protocol the data will be transferred from crawling server and our backend server. We make use of spring framework. Is there any opensource crawling server available.

Comment: @vaibought I'm not sure about opensource projects, perhaps Apache Nutch might be helpful. Regarding the question about transferring the data - you may consider RMI, however it has some disadvantages like in-memory serialization of whole request. I'd like to recommend to use shared folder, accessible through FTP/SFTP. You download content, then serialize it to the file (like putting a lot of COPY queries for quick import into Postgres), then copy it to server (FTP/SFTP). On server you scan the folder, then import data into Postgres. We found that it's fastest solution.

Comment: Can we make this happen like this. store the parsing html in mongo db and send some request to backend server. on the request basis (probably some id), the backend server will serch the mongo db and do the work with the data. How much efficient this method in terms of 500 - 1000 concurrent requests and mongo database optmization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing a crawling project based on [Selenium HtmlUnit Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver). I think it's really the best Java Framework to automate a headless browser.

Comment: Selenium can also be used with other driver implementations that can control external real world browsers, like Internet Exporer or Firefox, to ensure the maximum compatibility with HTML, CSS and Javascript.